# How can I receive AJAX POST data and save to EF Core using .Net Core

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have been at this for hours so hoping for even a push in the right direction. I was able to get my jquery AJAX post to send the data and can see it send in the post request. Turns up null always on the controller side. I have tried adding [FromBody] and it crashes the app, I have tried a few others on stackoverflow that didnt work either. They still dont receive anything it can read. I am working with .net core. This is my jquery code. Even trying to get one form field is blank..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $("#cosubmitbutton").click(function () {
                if ($('#VID').val() == "-1" || $('#VID').val() == "0") {
                    toastr[Error]("Please select company / Client!");
                    return false;
                }


                var dataObjects = { 
                
                TechnicalContact: $("#TechnicalContactId").val(),
                TCEmailAddress: $("#TCEmailAddressId").val(),
                NumOfWorkstations: $("#NumOfWorkstationsId").val(),
                NumOfUsers: $("#NumOfUsersId").val(),
                NumOfServers: $("#NumOfServersId").val(),
                NumOfFirewalls: $("#NumOfFirewallsId").val(),
                NumOfSwitches: $("#NumOfSwitchesId").val(),
                NumOfAps: $("#NumOfApsId").val(),
                Domain: $("#DomainId").val(),
               };


                //ObjThreadItem = JSON.stringify({ 'ObjThread': ThreadItem});

                console.log("Json Stringify CommonPostData: ", JSON.stringify(dataObjects))
                $.ajax({
                    
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    url: `@Url.Action("CreateCompanyOverview", "Client")`,
                    type: "post",
                    data: JSON.stringify(dataObjects),
                    success: function (result) {
                        debugger
                        toastr[success]("Information successfully updated on server!");
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        debugger
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            });

    </script>
```

Current Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult CreateClientOverview(string TechnicalContact)
{
    //ClientOverview clientoverviewlist = new ClientOverview();
    //{
    //    //technicalContact = TechnicalContact;
    //}
    //_context.ClientOverview.Add(model);
    //_context.SaveChanges();
    return Json(TechnicalContact);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API method should expect to receive an object instead of a string. And map to (database) entity model manually or look for the external library such as [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/).

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult CreateClientOverview([FromBody] TechnicalContactModel model)
{
    // TO get value from request body Example:
    // model.TechnicalContact 

    ...

    return Json(model);
}
```

And create a DTO / model class:

```cs
public class TechnicalContactModel
{
    public int TechnicalContact { get; set; }
    public string TCEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public int NumOfWorkstations { get; set; }
    public int NumOfServers { get; set; }
    public int NumOfFirewalls { get; set; }
    public int NumOfSwitches { get; set; }
    public int NumOfAps { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
}
```

Note: The above class illustrates the sample class with properties, make sure that the properties' name and type are correct according to the front-end and database model.

Comment: So I have actually set it up this way in one of my tests, or even now and I get a 405 Site Error as soon as I add the [FromBody].  Once I add [FromBody] it wont run the action or trip the breakpoints. Taking it off and it then does at least try to run it and stops at the breakpoints in the action. So I believe this is where I am getting hung up. I do like this Automapper! I did not know about this so thanks for that info too :-)

Comment: @TrixRahbit  I tried it and Yong Shun's answer worked just fine without getting a 405 site error.I think you can try to build a simplest example first, and then add your logic into it.